# Request custom permission with protection level=signature with a mismatch signature?

Tags: android, security, digital-signature

Let's say I have a server app that declares a custom permission called **com.testpackage.mypermission**, which is needed to start **ServerActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testpackage.myserver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" android:label="my_permission" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:permission="com.testpackage.mypermission"
            android:name=".ServerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then I have a client app that request **com.testpackage.mypermission** in its Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" />
```

I know that if the 2 apps are signed with different certificates, client app won't be able to start **com.testpackage.myserver.ServerActivity** because of protectionLevel=signature.

My question is:

1. If server app is already installed, and then I want to install
   client app, are their signatures checked at that moment? Or is it only checked at run time when you do **startActivity(ServerActivity)** in client app?
2. From my experience the answer to Q.1 seems to be runtime only. This confuses me, because standard system permissions (eg. **android.permission.CAMERA**) are checked at install time. So are custom permission and standard permission treated differently?

Thanks